# First use of curly braces to denote a set?

Tags: notation, set-theory

I was wondering who was the first person to

- Use curly braces to represent a finite set. Exempli gratia, $\{1,2,3\}$.
- Use set builder notation. Such as $\{2n:n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ to represent the even numbers. I am not sure if the colon or vertical pipe is the original form for set builder notation, I have seen both used, but the colon comes out better in $\TeX$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Georg Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor) was the first; see at least:

- ["Beiträge zur Begründung der transfiniten Mengenlehre (1)"](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichael/EmA/EmA_Briefe/EmA_Kapitel_4/ema_21_Cantor.pdf) (1895), *Mathematische Annalen*, 46, Engl.transl.[P.E.B.Jourdain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Jourdain) ([1915](https://archive.org/details/contributionstof00cant), also Dover reprint):

> By an "aggregate" (*Menge*) we are to understand any collection into a whole $M$ of definite and separate objects $m$ of our intuition or our thought. These objects are called the "elements " of $M$.
>
> In signs we express this thus :
>
> $$M = \{ m \}.$$

---

The formal [set builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Formal_set_builder_notation_sets) notation:

> $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$

is an evolution of W&R's [Principia Mathematica](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/) notation for "abstraction": $x \in \hat z(\psi z) \equiv \psi x$.

An early example is in:

- [Paul Bernays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Bernays), [Axiomatic set theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=YVKVAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA46) (1958, Dover reprint), page 46:

> The class operator $\{ x \mid \mathfrak A(x) \}$ "the class of the $x$ such that $\mathfrak A(x)$" [*footnote* : This symbol (used in some newer papers) is here taken, for the sake of easier print, instead of Russell's class symbol $\hat x \mathfrak A(x)$, whose adoption was first intended.]

---

The 2nd French edition of:

- Nicolas Bourbaki, [Théorie des ensembles](https://books.google.it/books?id=VDGifaOQogcC&printsec=frontcover) (2éme ed., 1970), page E.II.4 adopts it:

> On introduira [...] un symbole fonctionnel; dans ce qui suit, nous utiliserons le symbole $\{ x \mid R \}$; le terme correspondant ne contient pas $x$. C'est de ce terme qu'il s'agira quand on parlera de «l'ensemble des $x$ tels que $R$». [...] par suite la relation $R$ est équivalente à $x \in \{ x \mid R \}$.

The notation was not present in the [English translation of 1968](https://books.google.it/books?id=7eclBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. And thank you for the links, they will help me answer further questions.